# Категории товаров: один универсальный файл или для каждой категории свой файл?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В интернет-магазине 6 категорий товаров. Каждая категория должна отображаться на отдельной странице

Мне под каждую категорию создавать свой php-файл и страницу? Если да, то как это технически выглядит? Например, какие рекомендации по названию файлов, какими функциями пользуются для этого и т.д.

Или есть вариант, чтобы создать всего одну страницу и один php-файл, где код настроен таким образом, что подгружаются товары только заданной категории?

Наверное, возможны оба варианта. Какой из них легче реализовать и поддерживать в дальнейшем?

ПС. Если это важно, то опыт html/css/js на уровне где-то джуниора у меня есть. Опыта работы с бэкендом нету

Comment: Что значит "на отдельной странице"? Они и так "на отдельных" будут.

Comment: @SeVlad, технически ведь можно на одной странице создать 1) один список товаров, в котором будут товары разных категорий, или же 2) несколько списков, в каждом из которых будут товары только одной категории. Поэтому на всякий случай сделал уточнение, что меня интересует выводить товары одной категории только на одной странице.

Comment: "Страница категории" и выведет товары только из этой категории. (в любой нормальной теме)

Comment: @SeVlad, но я же свою тему пишу. Точнее на основе родительской. Другими словами у менять есть разметка, стили и скрипты и я их интегрирую на ВП. Поэтому "выведет товары только из этой категории" - это мне надо вручную сделать. По итогу - мой вопрос выше актуален. (В следующие разы, когда буду задавать вопросы на похожие темы, то буду уточнять этот аспект)

Comment: Надо не свою писать (тем более что нет знаний для этого), а делать дочернюю

Comment: @SeVlad, уважаемый, так и делаю. И в сообщении выше я оговорил это: "Точнее на основе родительской".

Comment: "На основе" и "дочерняя" - совершенно разные вещи. И я ответил - при использовании любой нормальной темы всё будет как надо без всяких доп телодвижений.